# How to load NSArray in steps on UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

```
-(void)addMyButton
{
  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.tag = 1;
  [button setTitle:@"Show More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 430.0, 100.0, 40.0);    
  [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad    
{
  [self addMyButton];   // Call add button method on view load
   n=1;   
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if(n==1){       
      n++;   
      return 10;       
   }
  else if(n==2){        
      n++;
      return 20;
   }
  else
     return 30; 
}

-(void) aMethod
{
   if(n>=3)   
   {
     [button setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   //[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
   }
   else{
     // [button setTitle:@"Show More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     // [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   }   
   NSLog(@"n==>>  %d",n);
  [tbl reloadData];
 }
```

An  array having thirty elements when i click ok return button then it should be shows twenty elements on TableView after next clicked i should shows ten elements and so on..

Comment: Please reformat your code (and add some more explanation of what you're trying to achieve) - this is unreadable.

Comment: hey? r u  there please analysis the problem.

Comment: one thing: you should not increase the `n` in `numberOfRowsInSection:` ... `aMethod` would be a better place to do this

Comment: If you are trying to achieve load more functionality. Then this approach is not better, Please search for more answer & you will get good approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're almost there.

You need `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` from the UITableViewDataSource protocol. This method effectively links the correct index in your array to a UITableViewCell.

e.g. something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: what is the titleLabel?

Comment: I've edited it to show a standard UITableViewCell implementation. Change "myArray" to your NSArray property.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the edited code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  if(n==1)   
    {       
      n++;   
        return 20; //edited from return 10 to  return 20-- to return 20 elements for the first time         
    }
 else if (n==2)   
   {        

   return 30;   //Return 30 when click on view more
   }

}


-(void) aMethod
{
 if(n==2)    
 {
   [button setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  //[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
 }
else   
 {
    n=1;
    [button setTitle:@"Show More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}   
  NSLog(@"n==>>  %d",n);
 [tbl reloadData];

}
```

try my code and let me know if i miss anything according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

try like this....

```
 #import "YourTableViewControllerClass.h"

@interface YourTableViewControllerClass ()
{
    NSMutableArray * tableArray;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"]];
}
-(IBAction)addMoreCells // button action to add more cells
{
    [tableArray addObjectsFromArray:@[@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20"]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return tableArray.count ;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: This is the write code but this not the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    -(void)addMyButton
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = 1;
    [button setTitle:@"Show More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 430.0, 100.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addMyButton];   // Call add button method on view load
    n=2;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if( [your_array count] <= (n*10)){

        n=1;
        return [your_array count];
    }
    else
    {

        return n*10;
    }

    return 0;
}


-(void)aMethod
{
    n++;


    if([your_array count]<=n*10){
        [button setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        [button setTitle:@"Show More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }





    [tbl reloadData];
}
```

Also add the code to set the data in table view cell (from your array) inside this method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can check the functionality by using the dummy code given below,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row+1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is not solution of the problem.

Comment: Then please try to explain your question clearly. Do you want to show the next 10 items (or append the next 10 items with the current) each time you click the button.?

Comment: Appends the next ten elements with the current